# how do I enforce type discrimination in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript if you have two interfaces and as a union type, why doesn't it discriminate which type members you can declare?

```
interface IFish {
  swim: () => void;
}

interface ICat {
  meow: () => void;
}

type Pet = IFish | ICat;

const pet: Pet = {
  meow: () => {
    //
  },
  swim: () => {
    //
  }
};
```

Comment: i'm expecting typescript to allow meow OR swim not both

Comment: Logically an OR means in english terms, P and/or Q. That is to say the only way that P|Q is false is if P and Q are both false. P and Q can both be true and there is no issue with that

Comment: See answer in [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346958/unexpected-behaviour-using-index-type-with-union-type-signature) and try `Xor<IFish, ICat>` if you want something like exclusive unions.  @MikhailBurshteyn's answer is also fine.

Comment: @jcalz I would have gone with a more general answer for this one. Just for two types in a union is pretty restrictive. I think we can do better with something like this: `type Pet = { swim: () => void; } | {meow: () => void;};
type NoExcessPropertiesHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof TAll>, never> : never;
type NoExcessProperties<T> = NoExcessPropertiesHelper<T, T> 
const pet: NoExcessProperties<Pet> = { meow: () => { }, swim: () => { } };`

Answer (score 2):

Your interfaces define which members an object must have, but it doesn't define which members an object may not have.  As a result, it is allowed for an `IFish` to have a `swim` method and vice versa.

Take a look at the updated example:

```
interface IFish {
    swim: () => void;
    meow: undefined;
}

interface ICat {
    meow: () => void;
    swim: undefined;
}

type Pet = IFish | ICat;

const pet: Pet = {  // compilation error here
    meow: () => {
        //
    },
    swim: () => {
        //
    }
};
```

Here it is explicitly stated that an IFish must not define `meow`, and an ICat must not define `swim`.  However, the problem with this approach is that if you have more than 2 interfaces and methods, you'll have to add a lot of these `undefined`s to your type definitions.