# Defining a choice of index type on an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say i have an interface Animal, and i want it to have some general properties, and then either be a cat or a dog and have corresponding properties.

```
interface Dog {
    dog: { sound: string; }
}

interface Cat {
    cat: { lives: number; }
}

type CatOrDog = Cat | Dog;

interface Animal {
    weight: number;
    // index type of CatOrDog
}
```

So i was thinking

```
interface Animal {
   weight: number;
   [K in keyof CatOrDog]: CatOrDog[K];
}
```

But TypeScript gets very angry when i use anything else than the `[K:string]: type`

What i am trying to achieve is

```
// Success
const dog = <Animal> {
    weight: 5,
    dog: {sound: "woof" }
}

// Error, lives doesn't exist on Dog
const errorAnimal = <Animal> {
    weight: 5,
    dog: {sound: "woof" },
    cat: { lives: 9 }
}
```

Also, if i wanted to add more index types, would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unions like `Cat | Dog` are [inclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), meaning that something is a `Cat | Dog` if it is a `Cat` or a `Dog` or *both*.  TypeScript doesn't have a general [exclusive union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.  If your unions share a common property with distinct values, you can use discriminated unions like @MateuszKocz suggests.  Otherwise, you could [build your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355289/2887218) `Xor` type function for objects:

```
type ProhibitKeys<K extends keyof any> = { [P in K]?: never }

type Xor<T, U> = (T & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>>) |
  (U & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>);
```

Then you can define `Animal` as the exclusive union of `Cat` and `Dog`, [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) with the additional properties common to all `Animal`s:

```
type Animal = Xor<Cat, Dog> & { weight: number };
```

Now you can get your desired behavior (type annotations are superior to type assertions so I am using those here):

```
// Success
const dog: Animal = {
  weight: 5,
  dog: { sound: "woof" }
}

// Error, {lives: number} not assignable to undefined
const errorAnimal: Animal = {
  weight: 5,
  dog: { sound: "woof" },
  cat: { lives: 9 }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I was hoping for an `interface`, but i see that it can't be expressed properly. I figured out how to do more than two elements Xor<a, Xor<b, c>>

Comment: It's also possible to turn an inclusive union into an exclusive one (`type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;  type MultiXor<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? U extends any ? U & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<AllKeys<T>, keyof U>> : never : never);)` And then you can use `MultiXor<a | b | c>` instead of `Xor<a, Xor<b, c>>` but whichever way works for you.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours now using `T extends any[]` but ended up having 4 Xors, and the first and last element were possible. Advanced types are quite scary, but it's a very small language that works be great to have in my arsenal

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change your code a bit, then [tagged unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) will be the answer you're looking for.

```
interface CommonAnimal {
  weight: number
}

interface Dog extends CommonAnimal {
  // This is the important part. `type` a tag used by TS to recognise this type.
  type: 'dog'
  sound: string
}

interface Cat extends CommonAnimal {
  type: 'cat'
  lives: number
}

type Animal = Dog | Cat

const dog: Animal = {
  type: 'dog',
  weight: 10,
  sound: 'woof'
}

const cat: Animal = {
  type: 'cat',
  weight: 5,
  lives: 9
}

const robot: Animal = {
  type: 'robot' // error
}
```

That way you'll be able to keep values on one level, without nesting, while satisfying TS's type recognition.

Comment: This is not possible. I am generating TypeScript interfaces based on an xsd schema, where i want to convert <Choice> into indexed types. So the properties have to be `cat` and `dog` right now it ends up being a bunch of optional properties, and no way to tell the structure without looking at the schema