# Is it possible to create a type with a generic rest type?

Tags: typescript

Following the question on creating a choice between types [Defining a choice of index type on an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753845/defining-a-choice-of-index-type-on-an-interface)

I now have to create a sequence of elements, usually it can be written as `element1 & element2`, but since i am converting an XSD schema i want it to be a 1-to-1 match, so that new TypeScript developers won't be confused with what is going on.

Currently i have this type

```
type Object_Type<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
type Sequence<A, B = {}, C = {}, D = {}, E = {}, F = {}, G = {}, H = {}, I = {}, J = {}, K = {}, L = {}, M = {}, N = {}> =
    Object_Type<A>
    & Object_Type<B>
    & Object_Type<C>
    & Object_Type<D>
    & Object_Type<E>
    & Object_Type<F>
    & Object_Type<G>
    & Object_Type<H>
    & Object_Type<I>
    & Object_Type<J>
    & Object_Type<K>
    & Object_Type<L>
    & Object_Type<M>
    & Object_Type<N>;
```

And can be used like this

```
const sequence: Sequence<{name: string}, {age: number}> = {
    name: "John",
    age: 999
};
```

However, it is quite extreme to manually have to define every single generic parameter, and also giving them a default value, so i was wondering if it was possible to define like so

```
type Sequence<...T> = Object_Type<...T>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no explicit [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) in TypeScript, so the exact formulation like `Sequence<...T>` doesn't work.  But you could use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) instead as in `Sequence<[{name: string}, {age: number}]>`.  Given a tuple type you could [map it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) with `Object_Type`, convert the tuple to a union by [looking up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) its `number` property, and then [convert the union to an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218).

```
type Object_Type<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type Sequence<T extends any[]> = 
  UnionToIntersection<{ [K in keyof T]: Object_Type<T[K]> }[number]>;

const sequence: Sequence<[{ name: string }, { age: number }]> = {
  name: "John",
  age: 999
};
```

That works, although there might be some edge cases that differ (e.g., if your individual `A`, `B`, etc types are themselves unions).  These could likely be hammered out, but... I guess I don't understand the use case here.  `Object_Type` is mostly a no-op, so what are you doing with it?  What do you gain by the expression `Sequence<A,B,C>` (or `Sequence<[A,B,C]>` in my version) that you don't get by `A & B & C`?  Maybe if you elaborate, there'd be an easier or better solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The use case is mostly for developers who aren't used to TypeScript, then when they look at the XSD schema and the index.d.ts generated, then they see the similarities. `Object_Type` was so i didn't have to write `{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] }` over and over again. I changed Sequence to `type Sequence<T extends any[]> = UnionToIntersection<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] }[number]>;`. Also the lookup type [number] is that like writing T[0], T[1], T[N], so it checks through every T in the array? Is it possible to do `number-1`, For the Xor use case which you helped me with earlier.

Comment: `{[P in keyof T]: T[P]}` is pretty much equivalent to `T`, especially for types like `{name: string}`.  Why are you not just using `T`?

Comment: `T[number]` is just looking up the value at the [`number` index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), which all arrays (even tuples) have.  It is conceptually the same as saying `T[0] | T[1] | T[2] | ... ` for all number literals, but it is not implemented that way.  The `number` type is a type for all numbers, so I'm not sure what you mean by `number-1`.

Comment: I see that `boolean` is not allowed tuple parameter when writing `T[number]`, that was my worry. For the second comment, It was the `Xor<A, Xor<B, C>>` problem, where it would be written as `Xor<T[number], T[number+1]>` where `T[number+1]` would be the result of evaluating `T[number+1]`, so `Xor<[A,B,C]> = Xor<A, Xor<B, C>>`

Comment: I'm really not following you, unfortunately.  I don't understand "`boolean` is not allowed tuple parameter when writing `T[number]`".  Can you provide concrete examples of what you mean?

Comment: `T[number+1]` is not valid code (neither `+` nor `-` are type operators) but *possibly* what you want to do is programmatically turn a tuple type like `[A, B, C, D]` into `Xor<A, Xor<B, Xor<C, D>>>`, which would be a recursive definition (which would probably run afoul of some limitations), but in the specific case of `Xor` you can write a version which acts on unions and so you can just do `MultiXor<[A, B, C, D][number]>`.  So again I'm kind of stumped about what you mean without concrete code examples... and probably in a different question (or an edit to this one) and not in comments.

Comment: `type Sequence<T extends any[]> = 
  UnionToIntersection<T[number]>;` `const sequence: Sequence<[{name: string}, boolean]>` is not allowed because it can't be both an object and a boolean. The link in the top of the question, is where you helped me making a MultiXor. This question was kind of a followup question to Defining a choice of index type on an interface