# Union type doesnt work as 'one of several types'

Tags: typescript

> [A union type describes a value that can be one of several types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

I want to define type union of A and B types. As far as I understood from docs the resulting type should be the type that represents A or B type. Surprisingly I'm able to have both `paramA` and `paramB` in `UnitedAB` type. Why does this happen and how do I create the type that will return `type A or type B` result?

```js
type A = {
  paramA: any;
};

type B = {
  paramB: any;
};

type UnitedAB = A | B;

const a: UnitedAB = { paramA: 1, paramB: 2 }; //OK (WHY?)
const b: UnitedAB = { paramA: 1}; //ok
const c: UnitedAB = { param12: 1}; //error
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Does Typescript support mutually exclusive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types)

Comment: @jcalz this might be easier to find for beginners as me + none of answers in that question duplicates current answer

Comment: Also possibly duplicate of [Defining a choice of index type on an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777729/2887218).  It seems to me that when you say "`A` or `B`" you mean *exclusive* or, which isn't a built-in type operator in TS.  If the linked questions don't address your problem, let me know.  As far as I can tell the answer below doesn't address this issue, but I'd be happy to be shown otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The important part here is later on in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

> **Union types can be a bit tricky here**, but it just takes a bit of intuition to get used to. **If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have.** In this example, Bird has a member named fly. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as Bird | Fish has a fly method. If the variable is really a Fish at runtime, then calling pet.fly() will fail.

Normally, you would knowingly have an `A` or a `B` and assign it to a property or parameter that accepts `A | B` but *also* have some way for that code to know or discern later which of `A` or `B` it actually is.

The next section in the documentation, [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) covers ways to do this.

Here is an example:

```
class A {
  type = 'A';
  paramA: any;
};

class B {
  type = 'B';
  paramB: any;
};

type UnitedAB = A | B;
function isA(aOrB: A | B): aOrB is A {
  return aOrB.type === 'A';
}

function isB(aOrB: A | B): aOrB is B {
  return aOrB.type === 'B';
}

const a = new A();

function takesAOrB(aOrB: A | B): void {
  if (isA(aOrB)) {
    console.log(aOrB.paramA);
  } else if (isB(aOrB)) {
    console.log(aOrB.paramB);
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AuBPADgU2gF5oByWEgblXRzACcwBbWALmjADssqUBfH1KEgwAQomqZcBYiRGUJtBoxFtO3VP1Sps+aAFUOASwx4AJrDHF4AH2gieAMwCuHYBkMB7DtEMRYACjAAeToVOGhbEQBKVRCxX3DkNGg6PAwnOm9g0IA6HWlCGXIeXi0UZ1d3Lx8IEUC4ths7GPY4mrtxZNT0zNbc-KJC0jkSsuAvCAx2ImgOPAB3OH8ogXKXN09vDDAAazw-OPrQxojmtgA3D0NTTvRDB2h-XwDs6Kjb9GhxjggPEDwciAPABzI4iHKKJiwFYSXjQPAgCAEe6PXx1V5Rd5JT5fCZ-AFA0GvCH0JjRHjoUp8MpAA)

Comment: any way to get `A or B` type? so user will not be able to use `paramA` and `paramB` simultaneously on resulting type?

Comment: I added to my answer. You would use type narrowing functions that "know" how to discern an `A` from a `B`, and then your code can use the `A` properties or `B` properties only.

Comment: I don't see that this answer addresses the question: why does the type `A | B` accept values assignable to *both* `A` *and* `B`, also known as `A & B`?  The answer is that the "or" in a union type is *inclusive*, not *exclusive*.  Exclusive object unions are more complicated to express in TypeScript but possible with conditional types, as shown in the answer to the linked question above.

Comment: @jcalz yes, that problem can be solved, but we don’t need to if we focus on declaring / creating objects of a narrow type before using them in a union context. I write code like this all of the time and never found the need to use an “exclusive object union”. I’m sure use-cases exist, but I do not see a critical need for it here. Hence, I’ve tried to answer how one can use a Typescript Union Type to deal with something that is one type or the other.